# What do the acronyms AOF and RDB stand for in Redis?

Tags: redis, persistence

I'm reading the Redis documentation on persistence here - https://redis.io/topics/persistence - and am wondering what the acronyms AOF and RDB stand for. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

`AOF` stands for Append Only File.  It's the change-log style persistent format.

`RDB` is for Redis Database File.  It's the snapshot style persistence format.

Comment: By default Redis saves snapshots of the dataset (`RDB`) on disk, in a binary file called _dump.rdb_.

Comment: it would be great if you also mention the difference between both.(like what is change-log style vs snapshot style)

Answer (score 70):

I would like to make an update @Tague's answer (for RDB) and also adding a basic info for each.
Both of these are options if one has to choose persistence for Redis data.
**`RDB`** is for **Redis Database Backup** file.
RDB file is a dump of all user data stored in an internal, compressed serialization format at a particular timestamp which is used for point-in-time recovery (recovery from a timestamp).
**`AOF`** stands for **Append Only File**.
AOF is actually a persistence technique in which an RDB file is generated once and all the data is appended to it as it comes.

Comment: This is a more complete answer, thank you!